# Livewire fire method when we type into input element

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

every users when they went to register our website and they are typing `username` or `email`, we want to check real time which `username` or `password` exists in our database or not. for implementing this feature i have this `input` element in `blade`:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"
       wire:model.lazy="username"
       value="{{old('username')}}">
```

as i'm not sure this implementation is correct i don't have any method on `component`.

for example:

```php
public function username($username){
    echo "Hey {$username} !";
}
```

i want to know how we can fire method when we type into `input` element

Comment: have you try wire:model..debounce.500ms="username" ? in Component, `updatedUsername()` will be called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`lazy`](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#lazy-updating) directive modifier on your `input` prevents a request being sent to the server when the field is updating (150ms default debounce). If you want to provide feedback as they type, remove the `lazy` modifier.

In order to determine if the `username/email` is in use, you'll want to hook into the lifecycle of your `username` property. By this I mean the `updatedUsername` function which will fire when the value of your `username` property updates in the Livewire component.

You could do something like the following (works with or without the `lazy` modifier on the input field):

**Livewire view**

```
<div>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text" value="{{ old('username') }}"
           wire:model="username">
    <p>{{ $availability }}</p>
</div>
```

**Livewire component**

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\User;
use Livewire\Component;

class RegisterForm extends Component
{
    public $username;

    public $availability;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.register-form');
    }

    public function updatedUsername()
    {
        if (User::where('email', $this->username)->first()) {
            $this->availability = 'That username is already taken';
            return;
        }

        $this->availability = '';
    }
}
```

Hopefully the above is self explanitory.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little note, when you wrote "*which username or password exists in our database*", I'm a little worried - I hope you don't check that passwords are unique, and I hope you hash them properly through the `Hash` facade.

---

The better approach is to define some `$rules` for your component, and use the built-in validation feature.

Alter your view to check for the validation errorbag instead,

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    class="form-control"
    wire:model.lazy="username"
/>
@error('username') {{ $message }} @enderror
```

Then make your component use validation through the `rules()` method, and using `validateOnly()` in your `updated()` hook.

```php
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class RegisterForm extends Component
{
    public $username;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.register-form');
    }

    public function updated($field)
    {
        $this->vbalidateOnly($field);
    }

    /**
     * The rules for this component
     */
    public function rules() 
    {
        return [
            'username' => [
                'required',
                'min:3',
                'unique:users,email',
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

See the [**official Livewire documentation on validation**](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/input-validation#real-time-validation).